# Executing SSIS job using powershell script in Azuredevops release pipeline

Tags: powershell, ssis, azure-devops, ssis-2012

I am using AzureDevops release pipeline to schedule SSIS job.
Job has multiple steps, if job fails for any reason the release pipeline still executes and gives Success message. How can I catch the job fail error and stop the release pipeline giving failure message. New to Azuredevops and powershell script.

Comment: Can you show your logs of this failing task?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej what exactly you want to see in the log ?

Comment: I have no idea unti I see them

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @Leo Liu-MSFT I used powershell script to catch the SQL Agent job error and used it as  a task in the release pipeline .

Answer (score 0):

> Executing SSIS job using powershell script in Azuredevops release pipeline

To resolve this issue, you could try to check if you are selected the checkbox
**Continue on error** for your powershell task:

[image]

If you are using YAML, try to remove `continueOnError: true` in you powershell task.

```
- task: string  # reference to a task and version, e.g. "VSBuild@1"
  condition: expression     # see below
  continueOnError: boolean  # 'true' if future steps should run even if this step fails; defaults to 'false'
```

If this not resolve your question, please share the configuration and build log of powershell task.